# Android, set visibility within list item layout

Tags: android, view, onclick, set

I am trying to display a delete button on every list item in my list view when the edit button is clicked.  I am using setVisibility elsewhere in the app, so I tried to copy that code, but the issue in that the layout elements in the list items are not part of the layout xml file that the fragment implements, they are in a special one used by my CursorAdapter. I can find the desired hide-able elements using a layout inflator so I no longer get a nullPonterException, however the visibility does not change on button click like it should.

```
//      Onclick method for Edit button
    final Button buttonE = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editNotesButton);
    buttonE.setTag(0);
    //cannot use rootView as that points to fragment_main
    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
    final View noteItemView = factory.inflate(R.layout.note_list_view_item, null);

    final LinearLayout deleteButton = (LinearLayout) noteItemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button_group);
    final LinearLayout circleButton = (LinearLayout) noteItemView.findViewById(R.id.circle_button_group);
    buttonE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {

           final int status =(Integer) v.getTag();
           if(status == 1) {
               buttonE.setText("Edit");
               circleButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               v.setTag(0); //pause
           } else {
               buttonE.setText("Done");
               circleButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               v.setTag(1); //pause
           }
       }
       }

    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,I will figure out why your code doesn't work.You inflate `noteItemView`,but it doesn't bind to view in the screen,that is your 'noteitemview' won't show forever,so your delete button in that view will not visiable.

    Then I will show my solution.
As you say,every list item has a delete button,what you should do is to control their visibility,so first make sure in your View binded to listview item has such a button as a childView of listview item view.In your `getView` of custom `CursorAdapter`,add logic to handle the delete button's visibility,for example,every list item data has a boolean variable named isDeleteButtonShow,then by control the variable's value to control the delete button's visibility,once visibility should change,update the data bind to listview and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.Hope that could help you.

Comment: Based off this method I got it to work, like you said I essentially defined whether the delete button would be there or not in the bindView and redrew once I altered the boolean, thanks.